# Devise - How to translate auto generated links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

I'm finishing the different localizations of my site and i got a little issue in Devise email templates.

In confirmation email for instance, i have translated it all, but the link to confirm the account is auto generated using this snippet:

```
<%= link_to t('devise.mailer.confirmation_instructions.confirm_link'), confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %>
```

This auto generated link points always to my .com web version and i want it to be conditional depending on the domain (.com/.es). When the link is not auto generated i can accomplish that using:

```
if request.host.split('.').last == "com"
```

or

```
if request.host.split('.').last == "es"
```

But in this case, i don't know how i can do it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: do you store current language setting somehow for the user?

Comment: You can pass the `:host` param to `url` helper.

Comment: I have a column in user's table in which i store the browser's language from the user. How could i pass the :host param? <%= link_to t('devise.mailer.confirmation_instructions.confirm_link'), confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token, :host => 'www.example.com') %> this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the :host param to your confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token), and look up the correct host in your translation table:

```
confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token, host: t('host'))
```

In your yaml file, you 'translate' the correct host for the user's language, like

```
en:
  host: 'www.example.com'
```